# Posso usar JSON para salvar ArrayLists em Shared Preferences?

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em um projeto da faculdade e estou criando a parte de controle, não vou mexer com a parte de servidor por enquanto pois não sei muito sobre.

Estou criando funções para gerar alguns `Arrays` com os itens da minha aplicação para que eu possa fazer testes, só que sempre que o aplicativo é fechado, esses dados são perdidos. Estava lendo sobre o *Shared Preferences*, que pode ser usado para armazenar pequenas quantidades de dados, e vi que posso usar o JSON para criar os `Arrays`.

Minha dúvida é se vai realmente resolver meu problema e se é uma boa ideia fazer isso. Eu havia pensando em armazenar em arquivo mas meu orientador já havia mencionado que a gente usaria o JSON para troca de dados com o servidor, então acho que não seria trabalho jogado fora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o JSON para salvar ArrayLists, utilizando, por exemplo, o JSONArray (https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), tem um exemplo no fórum internacional.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037340/converting-jsonarray-to-arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jArray != null) { 
   for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
    listdata.add(jArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
}
```

Mas vale ressaltar que a partir da API 11 é possível a utilização de StringSets, como ambas são coleções, a depender da sua necessidade, pode ser mais fácil essa manipulação.

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html